# How To move wordpress Multisite to Single Site with out losing any data and plugins

Tags: php, wordpress

I have Wordpress Multisite , and now i try to make my site to Single site in the same domain. I Tried taking Files and DB backup and moved those to single wordpress files and I get full data access but i cannot able to access admin panel it shows "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page" .

I deleted needed tables

wp_site

wp_sitemeta

wp_signups

wp_blogs

wp_blogversions

Comment: Go in your `wp_usermeta` table and check if `wp_user_level` is set to 10 for your admin user id.

Comment: You may want to delete primary_blog in that same table.

Comment: primary_blog ? Please let me know the table name fully @vard

Comment: `primary_blog` is a meta value that you can found too in `wp_usermeta`

Comment: Yeah i deleted that , but still i face the same problem @vard , I tried modifying the Wp-admin core files to check it wp-admin / inclues /menu.php and removed some code , and i made admin panel to login , but i cannot see any sections in admin area except profile section

Comment: "Go in your wp_usermeta table and check if wp_user_level is set to 10 for your admin user id". After doing this i can able to access admin section but i cannot see Apperance , plugins and other sections , please help any advice is appreciated :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87496/discussion-between-manoharsingh-and-vard).